# Add Tax Exempt form on checkout in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a form to my checkout page so when a user clicks the 'Tax Exempt' checkbox, a textbox will popup and ask the user what the Tax Exempt Id number is.

I got all of that working great, and I even added the `update_totals_on_change` class to my form field so it will update the totals.

My next step was to add an action/filter on a method so when the `update_totals_on_change` executes, I can set the tax to 0 and then it will finish calculating the total.

Does anyone know which functions I can hook on to?

Looking at the `checkout.js` file in `WooCommerce`, they set the action to `woocommerce_update_order_review` for the `ajax` operation.

I tried following that but soon got lost.

I was thinking I could add some post data by hooking in to `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review`

and then hooking in to `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` to modify the tax stuff, but I have no idea what I need to modify.

Am I even on the right path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I finally figured it out in case anyone is interested.

In my plugin, I made a form after the order notes by hooking in to this function: 'woocommerce_before_order_notes'

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', array(&$this, 'taxexempt_before_order_notes') );
```

my 'taxexempt_before_order_notes' function contained:

```
function taxexempt_before_order_notes( $checkout ) {

        echo '<div style="clear: both"></div>

        <h3>Tax Exempt Details</h3>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'tax_exempt_checkbox', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('tiri taxexempt'),array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
            'label'         => __('Tax Exempt'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'tax_exempt_checkbox' ));

        woocommerce_form_field( 'tax_exempt_name', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('form-row-first', 'tiri', 'taxexempt', 'textbox', 'hidden'),
            'label'         => __('Tax Exempt Name'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'tax_exempt_name' ));

        woocommerce_form_field( 'tax_exempt_id', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('form-row-last', 'tiri', 'taxexempt', 'textbox', 'hidden', 'update_totals_on_change'),
            'label'         => __('Tax Exempt Id'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'tax_exempt_id' ));
    }
```

Then the most important woocommerce function to hook was: 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review'

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', array(&$this, 'taxexempt_checkout_update_order_review' ));
function taxexempt_checkout_update_order_review( $post_data ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(FALSE);

        parse_str($post_data);

        if ( isset($tax_exempt_checkbox) && isset($tax_exempt_id) && $tax_exempt_checkbox == '1' && !empty($tax_exempt_id))
            $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);                
    }
```

I simply parsed out the $post_data that is the serialized form data from the checkout.js file in woocommerce and checked if my part of the form was filled out correctly.

If it was, then I would set the tax exempt for the user.

Comment: Notice! `$woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt` stores the value in database, so user who has *once* had tax exempt using that method, will have it next time too unless you set it to false! This is the reason the example above sets it to false always.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution didn't work for me, but I modified it to use the following:

```
//=============================================================================
// ADD TAX EXEMPT CHECKMARK
// =============================================================================
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'qd_tax_exempt');

function qd_tax_exempt( $checkout ) {

  echo '<div id="qd-tax-exempt"><h3>'.__('Tax Exempt').'</h3>';

  woocommerce_form_field( 'shipping_method_tax_exempt', array(
      'type'          => 'checkbox',
      'class'         => array(),
      'label'         => __('My organization is tax exempt.'),
      'required'  => false,
      ), $checkout->get_value( 'shipping_method_tax_exempt' ));

  echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'taxexempt_checkout_update_order_review');
function taxexempt_checkout_update_order_review( $post_data ) {
  global $woocommerce;

  $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(FALSE);

  parse_str($post_data);

  if ( isset($shipping_method_tax_exempt) && $shipping_method_tax_exempt == '1')
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);                
}
```

The key here is understanding that any field with a name that starts with `shipping_method` is going to inherit this updating order functionality (which was the part that didn't work for me). I found this answer at http://www.affectivia.com/blog/have-a-checkbox-on-the-checkout-page-which-updates-the-order-totals/

Comment: 'class' is a list of CSS classes to apply to the field, so it needs to be an empty array rather than an empty string.

Comment: @richplane, I updated my answer based on your comment. Thanks.

Comment: `parse_str()` without a second parameter is deprecated in PHP 7.2 (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).  The answer above should look like this `parse_str($post_data, $result);`, and then the next line should look like this: `if ( isset($result['shipping_method_tax_exempt']) && $result['shipping_method_tax_exempt'] == '1')`

Comment: @Jarom thanks for the feedback. I'm not going to update my answer because this is pretty old and I never tested it... but I feel confident that you are right :-)

Answer (score 2):

After a long search I found that there is a method for the cart object called remove_taxes() .
So, after setting a user meta for the tax exempt users, this cancels the tax totals.

```
function remove_tax_for_exempt( $cart ) {
    global $current_user;
    $ok_taxexp = get_the_author_meta( 'granted_taxexempt', $current_user->ID );
    if ($ok_taxexp){ // now 0 the tax if user is tax exempt
        $cart->remove_taxes();
    }
    return $cart;
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'remove_tax_for_exempt' );
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. I had already added a custom user profile field and was tracking if the user was tax exempt, but didn't know how to remove the taxes for just those users. This was the ticket!

Comment: remove_taxes() is deprecated since 3.2 - setting the user as is_tax_exempt(true) is the new way to do this (according to comments in the code).

Answer (score 0):

Because `$cart->remove_taxes();` is deprecated. This is what I used instead.

I didn't have a form on the frontend, but have a user roll that is tax exempt. This was my solution.

Also worth noting that `set_is_vat_exempt(true)` also works in the US to set as tax exempt.

```
/**
 * Set customer as tax exempt if user is a wholesale customer
 */
function remove_tax_for_exempt( $cart ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) ) {
        $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);
    }
    return $cart;
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'remove_tax_for_exempt' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this answer still pops up on google, I thought I'd share that setting the customer as tax exempt only works during checkout, if you need to edit the order on the back-end after it is placed and use the "recalculate" button, the taxes will still appear. Fortunately there is a hook for this as well:

```
function remove_tax_for_exempt($exempt, $order){
    return $exempt || user_can($order->get_user_id(), 'wholesale_customer');
}

add_filter('woocommerce_order_is_vat_exempt', 'remove_tax_for_exempt', 10, 2);
```