# How do I update the checkout cart with radio button to have no taxes?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to give tax exempt status to user on checkout by having them hit yes on radio button and then upload their tax exempt docs.

I got the radio and file upload working but can't seem to have it update the tax amount on the checkout page.

And I saw this solution [Add Tax Exempt form on checkout in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867447/add-tax-exempt-form-on-checkout-in-woocommerce) and tried altering to match my set up but it's not working. PHP is not my strong suit, so I'm sure I messed up somewhere.

Part that I'm having the issue with. It's not updating the tax.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'taxexempt_checkout_update_order_review');
function taxexempt_checkout_update_order_review( $post_data ) {
  global $woocommerce;

  $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(false);

  parse_str($post_data);

  if ( isset($uhave_tax_exempt) && $uhave_tax_exempt == '1')
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);                
}
```

Part that is working to display radio button and file upload.

```
function add_radio_field(){
    $radioFile   = "";
    $radioFile   .='<div class="customfield_cover"><label for="some_field_name" class="">Tax Exempt? </label><div id="radio_cover_id">';
    $radioFile .='<input name="uhave_tax_exempt" class="tax_exempt" type="radio" value="1" >Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="tax_exempt" name="uhave_tax_exempt" type="radio" value="2" >No';
    $radioFile .='</div></div>';
    echo $radioFile;
 }
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes','add_radio_field');

function add_file_field(){
     $uploadFile   = "";
     $uploadFile   .='<div class="customfield_cover custom_file_upload_cvr" style="display:none;" >
     <label for="some_field_name" class="">Attach tax exempt / Resale certificate </label>
     <div id="upload_CNIC_image" style="position:relative;left:15px;">';
     $uploadFile .='<input id="custom_file_upload" name="tax_exempt_attachmentfile" accept="file_extension|image/*|application/pdf|application/msword" type="file"  multiple="true" />
     <input type="hidden" value="" name="uploaded_docs" id="uploaded_docs" />
     <input type="hidden" value="" name="uploaded_docs_org" id="uploaded_org" />
     <div class="remove_uploaded"></div>
     ';
     $uploadFile .='</div></div>';
     echo $uploadFile;
 }
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes','add_file_field');
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not fully solve the situation but `$woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(FALSE);` will not work as the boolean values in PHP are all lower case so I would replace this line with `$woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(false);`

Comment: Thank You. Change made. Didn't effect the end result, but appreciated none the less.